# Server removes custom HTTP header fields

Tags: php, http, post, http-headers

I've been trying to receive HTTP requests with custom fields in the headers but it seems like my server removes them...

This is the request that I am sending to the server (I read that request with a HTTP Proxy) :

```
POST /oauth.php/request_token HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
User-Agent: DearStranger/1.0 CFNetwork/485.12.7 Darwin/10.6.0
Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="ebb942f0d260b06cb533c6133c28408004d343197", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="qPBFAa8XRRbor2%2F%2FQXv6kU3%2F7jU%3D", oauth_timestamp="1295278460", oauth_nonce="E7D6AC76-74CE-4951-8182-7EBF9B382E7E", oauth_version="1.0"
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

I printed the headers of the request when I arrive on my page.php. I see that :

```
uri http://domain.com/oauth.php/request_token
parameters 
headers Array
.... Accept : */*
.... Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
.... Accept-Language : en-us
.... Connection : keep-alive
.... Host : domain.com
.... User-Agent : DearStranger/1.0 CFNetwork/485.12.7 Darwin/10.6.0
method POST
```

when I should be seeing that (it is working on a local version)

```
uri http://localhost:8888/oauth.php/request_token
parameters 
headers Array
.... Accept : */*
.... Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate
.... Accept-Language : en-us
.... Authorization : OAuth realm="", oauth_consumer_key="582d95bd45d455fa2e5819f88fc0c5a104d2c7ff3", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="agPSFdtlGxXv2sbrz3pRjHlROOE%3D", oauth_timestamp="1295272680", oauth_nonce="667A133C-5071-48AB-9F13-8146425E46B7", oauth_version="1.0"
.... Connection : keep-alive
.... Content-Length : 0
.... Host : localhost:8888
.... User-Agent : DearStranger/1.0 CFNetwork/485.12.7 Darwin/10.6.0
method POST
```

I am using php 5.2.17 on the server.

Do you have any idea to help me fix that issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the real headers (or $_SERVER[]) instead of just the  values?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a firewall that's stripping the headers?  Lots of firewalls will white-list acceptable headers and remove all other ones.

Comment: Is there a (squid) proxy anywhere?

Comment: There is not proxy on the client side, but I don't know for sure about the server side because it is being hosted by a company.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache strips the Authentication header because it's a security risk, when used with CGI. Are you using PHP through CGI?

I think PHP also strips Authentication in some circumstances. Again, there's a risk that exposing it to scripts will allow one users' code to sniff other users' on the same server (e.g., if Alice and Bob both have accounts).

Comment: Yes I am using php with CGI. I didn't know that Apache strips the Authentication header... strange!

Comment: What is this Authentication header you talk of?

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is a pretty easy fix. The fault lays with fastcgi. You can just provide an .htaccess file with a rewrite rule to save the header.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

...

# Pass Authorization headers to an environment variable
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Credit goes here: https://drupal.org/node/1365168

They also talk about an even simpler solution to let these headers pass through, if you are using a virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

Please include the actual names of the headers that are being cut. This question is useless in its present form, forcing us to guess...

Have you checked with Firebug/HTTPFox that your browser's actually sending those headers? Unless you've specifically configured the server to clean up the headers, it's going to pass-through any custom ones as-is.

The Authorization header, which is where the OAuth data gets sent, would ONLY be sent by a client in response to a server-side 401 "authorization required" request. If you haven't added the server-side "must have password to get in" configuration, the client's not going to send auth info.

Comment: I have edited my message, you can now see the names of the headers. So the important one who is cut is called "Authorization". I've not checked yet with Firebug/HTTPFox anything because my request are being sent from an iPhone app, but for now it's sent from the iPhone simulator. I am making this http request after that the server sent a 401 Authorization required response.

Comment: Well, stick an HTTP proxy in there which can log the headers it sees incoming from the emulator. PHP by itself wouldn't strip headers, and Apache usually wouldn't either, so most likely your app isn't sending them.

Comment: And what could explain that on a local server it is working and not when I'm hosting my code somewhere else? I'm going to try to log the headers and I'll let you know...! Thanks a lot

Comment: So I just checked how to requests look like with a HTTP proxy and my requests are just fine, I can see the "Authorization" and its value in the header. I am really starting to think that something on the server side is removing my "Authorization" header. Do you have something else in mind that I could do to find the cause of my problem? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Check which modules are loaded in Apache. They might have have something like mod_security running, which would clean up headers.

Comment: I just checked and there is nothing like mod_security or another module activated that could remove my headers :(

Comment: I noticed that if I build a request with the header "Authorization2", this header makes his way to the server. It really looks like my server removes only the "Authorization" header... Strange

Comment: Have the same problem here. The Authorization header is getting stripped somewhere along the way to a php script (Apache 2, FastCGI, PHP 5.2.17). No problems sending the same request to a python cgi on the same machine.